# Set TextView Text from View class Not from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-custom-view

This is my Activity class . Here I have a Textview.
I want to Set the TextView from View Class.

```
public class TestApp extends Activity 
{

  TextView   NameTxtView;
  CustomView  view;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.Main); 
         view                       = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.customview);    

        NameTxtView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTxtxVw);

   }

}
```

This is my View Class. Here i want to set the TextView Text. I can't set this Text on Activity. Because I am getting value on View class.

```
public  class CustomView extends View
{
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
          super(context, attrs); 
    } 

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
          NameTxtView.settext("Test");

    }
}
```

Any Idea how to do that?

thanks

Comment: How you are using CustomView ?

Comment: I updated. I have added this is xml.

Comment: why you need to create custom view main layout is not enough?

Comment: You can do it using interface implementation in your view class

Comment: @Biraj Zalavadia How can you explain me little bit? . I am new in android. or else can you edit my question itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this way

**TestApp.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.demo.CustomView.CustmViewListener;

public class TestApp extends Activity 
{

  TextView   NameTxtView;
  CustomView  view;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.Main); 
         view   = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.customview);    

        NameTxtView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTxtxVw);

        view.setCustmViewListener(new CustmViewListener() {

            @Override
            public void onUpdateValue(String updatedValue) {
                NameTxtView.setText(updatedValue);
            }
        });

   }

}
```

**CustomView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomView extends View {

    CustmViewListener custmViewListener;

    public CustmViewListener getCustmViewListener() {
        return custmViewListener;
    }

    public void setCustmViewListener(CustmViewListener custmViewListener) {
        this.custmViewListener = custmViewListener;
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (getCustmViewListener() != null) {
            getCustmViewListener().onUpdateValue("passYourValueHere");
        }

    }

    public interface CustmViewListener {
        void onUpdateValue(String updatedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply Let me implement and see the behavior. one more doubt: What problem it will cause if I will   make NameTxtView static and access it directly on CustomView Like: TestApp.NameTxtView.settext("Test");

Comment: That's also work ... problem is you have to define that textview with class name(eg.TestApp.NameTxtView.setText....). so your customclass will not be generalized to all activities in app . it will depends to this TestApp activity only.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :
In CustomView Constructor call LayoutInflaterService and pass Id for your Layout & TextView :

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final RelativeLayout yourLayout = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_menu, null);
TextView myText = (TextView) yourLayout.findViewById(R.id.nameTxtxVw);
myText.setText("");
```

Comment: Compile time Error LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE  can not resolve to a variable

Comment: Use Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the activity class has a context and your second one does not. To solve this create a global variable: `static Activity activity` and initialize it in the constructor.

Then call: `new CustomClass(ActivityClass.this)`.

Next whenever you want to do something related to an activity simply put `activity.` in front of stuff